# re-attach sources in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm hoping to debug into the source code of jaxb-impl.

I downloaded version 2.2.6, attached the sources and then realized the app I'm debugging is using jaxb-impl version 2.2.3

So now that I have the correct version 2.2.3 of the source, I can't figure out how to remove the association from 2.2.6 source so that I can attach the 2.2.3?

Update: I figured out that you can go into the .idea directory, find the library xml def and remove all the stuff inside the `<sources>` tag. In my case, I edited  `libraries/Maven__com_sun_xml_bind_jaxb_impl_2_2_3_1.xml`.

Anyone know if there's a way to do this thru the GUI?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Project Structure` | `Libraries` (or [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) if libraries are defined there):

[image: sources]

In case Maven is managing the dependencies, `Download Sources` in the `Maven Projects` should also work:

[image: download]

Comment: Man, I can't believe I missed that - didn't realize I could double click on the library name in the Module Dependencies view. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! For such an easy option to set, they sure make it difficult to unset/reset it...

Comment: Sadly this not works for grails project (intellijIDEA v14.0).

Answer (score 1):

Another (non-GUI) option is to delete the downloaded source files from $USER_HOME$/.ideaLibSources/ and restart IntelliJ.  I'm working on a Grails project and didn't see anything relevant in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

`Project Structure` | `Libraries` (or [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) if libraries are defined there):

[image: Project Structure]

Then in the libries tab click on the plus mark:

[image: Libraries]

Select the source type.

[image: Add source]

Then you have to select the source path and add the wanted libraries finally click apply!